# Custom Xcode IDE Plugin error: "Could not find class named..."

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I've developed my own custom Xcode .ideplugin to add a custom object to Xcode's **Object Library** pane. I have my custom object template based on a class I called IBMyCustomObject, which in turn has a runtimeClassName of a class I called MyCustomObject (a runtime class name is the name of the class that will be instantiated at runtime when the Xib file is loaded).

After tons of research, I've been able to successfully get this working. I can now drag and drop my custom object from the Objects Library pane to Xib files normally, set the object properties in the inspector pane, and everything else is working great. The only problem comes at compile time, where Xcode's `ibtool` gives me the following error when the Xib file is compiled:

```
Exception name: NSInvalidArgumentException
Exception reason: Could not find class named MyCustomObject
```

And here is the full exception backtrace log:

```
Exception backtrace: 
  0. CoreFoundation           0x0226d6d8 __exceptionPreprocess
  1. libobjc.A.dylib          0x01fe98b6 objc_exception_throw
  2. CoreFoundation           0x022fd721 -[NSException raise]
  3. ???                      0x000116b8 [IBCocoaTouchToolObjectPackage initWithRequest:]
  4. ???                      0x00010597 [IBCocoaTouchTool .cxx_destruct]
  5. ???                      0x0000b63d [IBCocoaTouchTool compileNibForRequest:minimumCompatibility:layoutInfo:]
  6. IBFoundation             0x00362c51 __72-[IBMessageReceiveChannel deliverMessage:toTarget:withArguments:result:]_block_invoke
  7. IBFoundation             0x00362996 -[IBMessageReceiveChannel deliverMessage:toTarget:withArguments:result:]
  8. IBFoundation             0x00362673 __80-[IBMessageReceiveChannel runBlockingReceiveLoopNotifyingQueue:notifyingTarget:]_block_invoke
  9. libdispatch.dylib        0x029c2444 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke
 10. libdispatch.dylib        0x029d34b0 _dispatch_client_callout
 11. libdispatch.dylib        0x029c1766 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
 12. CoreFoundation           0x022d2b6e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
 13. CoreFoundation           0x022137eb __CFRunLoopRun
 14. CoreFoundation           0x02212bf3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
 15. CoreFoundation           0x02212a0b CFRunLoopRunInMode
 16. Foundation               0x01c1fe55 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]
 17. ???                      0x0003ac67 [IBAbstractCocoaTouchTool startServingReceiveChannel:]
 18. ???                      0x0003ad62 [IBAbstractCocoaTouchTool startServingSocket:]
 19. ???                      0x0003aec7 [IBAbstractCocoaTouchTool protocolCapabilities]
 20. ???                      0x0001053e [IBCocoaTouchTool .cxx_destruct]
 21. libdyld.dylib            0x9313d725 start
Exception info:{
}
```

Any ideas on how can I have Xcode (more specifically ibtool) know about the MyCustomObject class so that it could find it at compile time? I've tried many things, including placing MyCustomObject in a framework and loading the bundle at runtime, but nothing worked at all. If I replace IBMyCustomObject's runtimeClassName with NSMutableDictionary (or any other Foundation or UIKit class) instead of MyCustomObject, everything works perfectly, but I really need to use my own MyCustomObject class instead.

P.S.: For everyone interested in developing similar plugins, I'll be posing all my findings in a detailed blog post on [sensiblecocoa.com](http://sensiblecocoa.com) (the framework using the plugin) once I have everything figured out.

Comment: Same identical question is still applicable to Xcode 4.

Comment: You may want to clearify that by removing the Xcode5 subject?! .. just saying

Comment: @Till NDA doesn't make a post off topic.

Comment: I have retracted my vote due to the correction of the subject. @0x7fffffff I have seen these arguments all over SO but my opinion does not match the new "standard" - hence my initial vote.

Comment: Ok - let me clearify my initial vote (which has been retraced - it got 2 close votes, now its down to one). I never mentioned anything about an NDA. My angle is different; if a software developer (or vendor) ships a prerelease, he usually does that for one reason; to gather problem reports. If those problem reports are posted anywhere but on the developer's site, he most likely never gets that feedback. But once again, that is my personal opinion and the community may decide differently, that is the cool thing about SO.

Comment: @0x7fffffff More appropiate is this QA - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137726/limits-of-ios-6-nda/137727#137727

Comment: IB plugins have been deprecated since 4.x.  I'm not surprised this doesn't compile, nor should it if the folks who wrote IBFoundation have anything to say about it.

Comment: @CodaFi plugins haven't been deprecated, they just aren't publicly documented or supported anymore by Apple since Xcode 4.0. As a matter of fact, Apple uses plugins internally all the time to add functionality to Xcode.

Comment: @CodaFi is effectively correct. When the API isn't public, it means it's not intended for 3rd parties to use. If you feel so inclined, go forth and figure it out, but be prepared for when Apple changes the API without notice, breaking your plug-in, and for everyone's sake, don't try to sell software based on private API to customers.

Comment: @ipmcc I know from several sources that the API will eventually be made public. Furthermore, as a developer, I get early access to beta releases of Xcode and would easily be able to patch my code if anything were to change.

Comment: All your users will have the same beta releases, and will be miffed that the plug-in doesn't work. I get that you think you want to do this, and I can't stop you, but you should go in with eyes wide open. If the API were going to be made public in it's current form, it would be public. Which means it's going to change. Also this class-loading thing that you're hacking around is certainly something that would have to be sorted out before the API was made public. Do what you want, but down this road lies pain, I'm confident of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that Xcode (more specifically ibtool) is spawning an entirely new process called "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" during compile time, which explains why loading the `MyCustomClass` bundle had no effect. One possible solution to this that I considered was using dylib injection to inject the `MyCustomClass` library into the newly spawned process, but none of the techniques I found were reliable enough for robust and stable production code.

I finally ended up using `NSMutableDictionary` instead of `MyCustomClass`, which compiled perfectly. I then used a setter property method in the object owner class to convert the loaded `NSMutableDictionary` into `MyCustomClass`, then manually assigned all the dictionary keys to their respective properties. As I said before, I'll be posting all the plugin development details on the [sensiblecocoa.com](http://sensiblecocoa.com) blog page.