# Global system-wide Cocoa runtime library

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is it possible to create a system-wide runtime library that makes available a certain set of runtime classes available to all system running processes? The classes should be available in the sense that calling `NSClassFromString` for the class name from any Cocoa process will return a valid class.

**Note**: I can't load the library using `NSBundle` since I don't have access to some of the processes' code. To be more specific, I am trying to have some classes available to Apple's "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" process. For full details on why I need this, please refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403328/custom-xcode-ide-plugin-error-could-not-find-class-named).

Comment: Sounds like *dylib injection* and I cannot see how you'd hook it so early (i.e. in `launchd` itself).

Comment: I don't actually need to hook it early. Is it possible to monitor until the "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" process gets loaded and then inject the dylib?

Comment: You could hook it on the invocation of Xcode.  As covered by @ipmcc's answer; this would be "just on your machine" solution.

Comment: See my answer re: injecting library with GDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no.

In a few more words: I see two vectors to make this happen: force every process to dyld your framework somehow, or patch an existing system library that every Cocoa process will load to contain your classes.  Neither of these solutions are going to be useful for anything other than "just on your machine."

If you want a "just on your machine" solution, then an easier one would be to write a script that induces GDB/LLDB to attach to the process, causes your library to be loaded, and then detaches. That will be much easier than either of the hypothetical approaches above. Such a process might look like this:

```
your-machine:~ you$ lldb
(lldb) attach Finder
Process 331 stopped
Executable module set to "/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder".
Architecture set to: x86_64-apple-macosx.
(lldb) expr (char)[[NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/Path/To/Your/Framework.framework"] load]
(char) $0 = '\x01'
(lldb) detach
Detaching from process 331
Process 331 detached
(lldb) quit
your-machine:~ you$
```

As you must already know, the Xcode plug-in interface is not public, so you are already in unsupported, likely-to-change-out-from-under-you territory here.

Comment: Thanks @ipmcc. Why is this only limited to my machine? Can't I create an executable that monitors until my target process has been loaded then execute your above script (from within my executable) to inject the framework?

Comment: Sure, you could do that, however, there are going to be various permissions issues, and it'd probably require a launchd job to watch for new processes. In short, this is not going to be a good software experience for the person trying to use it. I certainly would not sell software as a product that pulled shenanigans like this (and it would *certainly* never be allowed on the App Store, not that it matters here since using private API would be the more significant offense.)

Comment: Thanks again @ipmcc, I'll probably take your advice and look for another solution.